# Scrape part of web page html and test it against condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is part of the html code from "view page source" I want to scrape

```
<span>Loyalty cijena</span>
                                <strong>863,84 KN</strong>
```

This is my code to scrape part which is now "863" and start my function if that number is under 863. But now the function start no matter condition is set [0-862] or [0-864]. Where is my mistake?

```
function createBackup() {
        var folder = getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
        var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl);
        var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
        var scraped = htmlBody.match(/Loyalty cijena<\/span>\s*<strong>(\d+),(\d+) KN<\/strong>/m)[1];
            if(scraped.match(/[0-862]/)); { 
            createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData());
        }
    }
```

Edit: This is full code

```
var RESOURCE_URL = 'https://www...',
    BACKUP_FOLDER_ID = 'xxx',
    FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    FILE_NAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",

    FILE_EXT = '.pdf',

    now = new Date(),
    FOLDER_NAME = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'CET', FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT),
    FILE_NAME = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'CET', FILE_NAME_FORMAT) + FILE_EXT;

function createBackup() {
    var folder = getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
    var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl);
    var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
  var scraped = htmlBody.match(/Loyalty cijena<\/span>\s*<strong>(\d+),(\d+) KN<\/strong>/m)[1];
  console.log(scraped,parseInt(scraped) > 0 &&  parseInt(scraped) < 863); { 
        createBackupFile(folder, FILE_NAME, fetchData());
    }
}

function getFolder(name) {
    var backupFolder = getBackupFolder(),
        folders = backupFolder.getFoldersByName(name);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
        folder = folders.next();
    } else {
        folder = backupFolder.createFolder(name);
    }
    return folder;
}

function getBackupFolder() {
    return DriveApp.getFolderById(BACKUP_FOLDER_ID);
}

function createBackupFile(folder, filename, data, overwrite) {
    if (overwrite) {
        var existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
        while (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
            var file = existingFiles.next();
            folder.removeFile(file);
        }
    }
}

function fetchData() {
    var exportUrl = RESOURCE_URL;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl);
    var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(FILE_NAME);
    return folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[0-862]` matches text that ends with `62` and where the first symbol is `0` to `8`, so for example `562` but not `561`. In your case you should compare the number represented by those characters, instead of matching against a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to match a value:

```js
var htmlBody = `<span>Loyalty cijena</span>
                                    <strong>863,84 KN</strong>`

var scraped = htmlBody.match(/Loyalty cijena<\/span>\s*<strong>(\d+),(\d+) KN<\/strong>/m)[1];
console.log(scraped, 
  parseInt(scraped) > 0 &&  parseInt(scraped) <= 863); // false if you change to < 863
```

Comment: Tnx @mplungjan When I run code snippet in your answer I see that gives true for this condition. But when I insert your code in my full code (original post edited) file creates although condition <863 isn't met. I've obviously make some other mistake but I couldn't find it.